# OpenLDAP - possible to search without specifying base?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am having some issues with OpenLDAP and Spring security, where the latter does a search with the whole path in dn (filter), and an empty base. OpenLDAP does not like this, and the query fails. The problem is that I have no control over the query, so I am thus wondering if it is possible to configure OpenLDAP to allow such queries.

Answer (score 1):

An empty base is a special case for retrieving information about the OpenLDAP server that can host several databases (or "namingContexts" or "bases"). E.g.:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -b '' -s base 'objectClass=*' +
```

There really should be some way of specifying the base to use for searches

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that Spring Security won't allow you to set an appropriate search base. Depending on your environment you may be able to get away with setting a default search base to the frontend config.

```
$ ldapmodify -f <<EOF
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
add: olcDefaultSearchBase
olcDefaultSearchBase: dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: I can try, so what should I change to fit my environment here? oldDefaultSearchBase only?

Comment: Yes. In some environments setting a default search base is not desirable. If this were the case in yours, you would know.

Comment: Hehe, I *should* know perhaps :) But I only have one search tree, and if I understand correctly this should be OK then..